# Immersion from $R^{2}$ to $R^{4}$

Tags: differential-geometry

If we have an immersion from $R^{2}$ to $R^{4}$ defined by
\begin{align}
\notag
f:(x,y) \to (x,y,x,y).
\end{align}
If basis of $R^{2}$ is $\{e_{1},e_{2}\}$ and basis of $R^{4}$ is $\{e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}=Je_{1},e_{4}=Je_{2}\}$, $J$ is an almost complex structure, how do we calculate 
\begin{align}
\notag
g(\nabla_{X}f_{*}Y,f_{*}Z),
\end{align}
for vectors $X$, $Y$, $Z$ tangent to $R^{2}$?

Comment: You could give us the definition of the terms in your last expression, or the reference book where they came from. And sharing what have you tried so far :-)

Comment: Of course. $g$ is simply a Euclidean metric on $R^{4}$. The connection $\nabla$ is defined as $\nabla = \nabla^{g} + K$. $\nabla^{g}$ is a Riemannian connection. $K$ is a tensor with some properties, so I calculated its coefficients according to them.

Comment: Calculation should go like this:

Comment: $f_{*}X=x_{1}e_{1} + x_{2}e_{2} + x_{1}e_{3} + x_{2}e_{4}$

Comment: $f_{*}Y=y_{1}e_{1}+y_{2}e_{2}+y_{1}e_{3}+y_{2}e_{4}$

Comment: $f_{*}Z=z_{1}e_{1}+z_{2}e_{2}+z_{1}e_{3}+z_{2}e_{4}$

Comment: and then we calculate

Comment: $g(\nabla_{x_{1}e_{1}+x_{2}e_{2}}y_{1}e_{1}+y_{2}e_{2}+y_{1}e_{3}+y_{2}e_{4},z_{1}e_{1}+z_{2}e_{2}+z_{1}e_{3}+z_{2}e_{4})=$

Comment: $x_{1}y_{1}g(\nabla_{e_{1}}e_{1},z_{1}e_{1}+z_{2}e_{2}+z_{1}e_{3}+z_{2}e_{4})+x_{1}y_{2}g(\nabla_{e_{1}}e_{2},z_{1}e_{1}+z_{2}e_{2}+z_{1}e_{3}+z_{2}e_{4})+$...

Comment: or I am wrong??